# how can fix this issue "Error in h2o.upload_model() : could not find function "h2o.upload_model"?

Tags: r, h2o

I have installed h2o package(in R from RStudio console). Post h2o.init() I am trying to use the built in function upload_model()/upload_mojo() but I am getting following error.

> h2o.upload_mojo()
> Error in h2o.upload_mojo() : could not find function "h2o.upload_mojo"
> h2o.upload_model()
> Error in h2o.upload_model() : could not find function "h2o.upload_model"

Comment: I have tried these upload functions for h2o versions = 3.22.1.1 as well as 3.31.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found work around to resolve this issue. Please find below the steps I followed:

1. Remove the package using: remove.packages("h2o")
2. Quit the current session and launch the new one.
3. Move out lock file for h2o from path where package was installed mostly under R with file name like - 00LOCK-h2o
4. Install new/latest version of package via RStudio console using install.packages()

It should now resolve this issue.